# Drag & Drop custom mesh formats into viewport

Tags: 3d-view, add-on, import, file-format

I have an add-on for importing/exporting a particular mesh format. Is there a way I can have drag & drop of this file type from the file browser into blender viewport automatically trigger my import add-on on that file(s) ? (similar to the way the drag & drop image into the viewport works).

Currently other import/export formats do not seem to work by simply drag&drop into viewport (e.g. obj, stl, dae).

Note: sure, some of these import add-ons provide additional settings before import/export, and one could argue that drag&drop is not useful, but still in some cases it can still be useful when predefined import settings can be assumed.